# Excel not sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

For some reason, when I try to sort in a file I downloaded, the sorting fails, even if there are just simple numbers in the cells. Editing is enabled.

What is going on?

**Edit**: When I say sort, I mean the following:

1. Select the range I want sorted
2. Hit the sort button
3. Select the column that I want it sorted by
4. Watch as the range remains unchanged.

**Edit 2**: The range is not quite unchanged. 5,1,2,3,4 is the least to greatest, and 3,4,5,1,2 is greatest to least. The latter order was the one that the data was entered in.

Comment: We need more information. An example of what you are working with would be really helpful.

Comment: It's really that simple. A random spreadsheet, no special formatting or protection, with a simple column of numbers. It won't sort. Nothing else to say really.

Comment: you need to select all cell you want sorted

Comment: @ratchetfreak, see edit.

Comment: Just curious, when you say it fails, do you mean nothing happens or you do get a excel error message?

Comment: @Jay, see edit.

Comment: Maybe it is sorting, but you can't see it. What I mean by this is that there could be hidden characters that look like a space preceding the numbers that you can see. When sorted, it's sorting by these hidden characters as they technically contain data.

Comment: @kobaltz, not the case, I just typed them in.

Comment: Is the worksheet protected? I know that whenever I download a Spreadsheet that it will sometimes have a warning at the top of the spreadsheet, indicating that I have to click a button to enable editing of the spreadsheet.

Comment: @kobaltz, see above, editing enabled. Plus, I typed the numbers in, so it must be enabled.

Comment: Where did the spreadsheet originate from? I've seen similar issues from spreadsheets that are 'generated' instead of originating from Excel. The generated spreadsheet may be missing certain tags or information that is causing it to not sort.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2085/discussion-between-kobaltz-and-soandos)

Answer (score 1):

I think excel does what you ask for exactly! If worksheet contains some empty rows, excel sorts until it encounters an empty row, and values after this empty row sorted again. I mean;
assume we have column like this

```
5
empty row
6
3
1
4
```

excel sorts this row like this;

```
5
empty row
1
3
4
6
```

However, this problematic empty row generally created by copy/pasting operations, especially selecting two table from a web page.

By the way, sorry for my poor english :(

Answer (score 0):

Click the sort button.

Is the "Sort on"  set to Values?

Is the "Order" set to Smallest or Largest - and especially not set to a custom list? (Perhaps also check in custom lists and delete any list that may interfere)

Check the cell type of your cells, are they all the same type, like Numeric or Text?

Others are suggesting trying it on a different spreadsheet. What about on a different column in the same sheet? Try Copy+Paste, and Copy+Paste Values. Any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I wasn't able to filter my numbers properly in my table. To fix this situation, I had to recreate my table headline from the table creation properties as illustrated below.

[image]